# Getting a ProximityPrompt to connect to a intvalue

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm currently working on getting this proximity prompt so when you click E on it, it'll change the number value on the UI system. I'm a little confused because when I set it all up it does not seem to be changing the number at all.

Code Connected to PP:

```
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function()
    game.ServerStorage.genact.Value = game.ServerStorage.genact.Value + 1
end)
```

Code Connected to UI:

```
while true do
    script.Parent.Text = ("Generators Activated: ")..game.ServerStorage.genact.Value
end
```

Any thoughts to fix this? I also have a intvalue inside the ServerStorage which these connect to, but it doesnt seem to change its value from 0

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the while loop never yields. It loops endlessly until it times out.

A better solution is to use the Changed signal on your IntValue. You use it to update the text input when it changes.

```lua
local genact = game.ServerStorage.genact
local textBox = script.Parent

genact.Changed:Connect(function(newVal)
    textBox.Text = "Generators Activated: " .. tostring(newVal)
end)
```